# Como comparar uma data do tipo datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Tenho uma data em uma tabela de paciente no banco Sql Server no seguinte formato:

```
datetime (01/01/2016 12:50:00.000)
```

Quero verificar se a hora da consulta do paciente chegou.

Por exemplo: A hora da consulta é às **13:00**, quero verificar se  hoje é o dia marcado e se esta na hora marcada. Como faço?

Comment: Quer fazer apenas em SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais simplificada para fazer isso é simplesmente comparando uma data com a outra `where data = @Data`, veja os exemplos abaixo.

```
declare @Data datetime = cast('01/01/2016 12:50:00.000' as datetime)
declare @paciente table
(
  id int,
  data datetime
)

insert into @paciente values
(1, GETDATE()),
(2, cast('01/01/2016 12:50:10.001' as datetime)),
(3, cast('01/02/2016 12:50:00.000' as datetime)),
(4, cast('01/01/2016 12:40:00.000' as datetime)),
(5, cast('01/01/2016 12:50:00.000' as datetime))

select * from @paciente
where data = @Data


-- ou 
select * from @paciente
where cast(data as date) = cast(@Data as date)
and cast(data as time) = cast(@Data as time)

-- ou 
select * , convert(varchar, data, 108) from @paciente
where year(data) = year(@data) 
and month(data) = month(@data) 
and day(data) = day(@data) 
and convert(varchar, data, 108) = convert(varchar, @data, 108)
```

Veja algumas dicas sobre datetime.

[Referencia 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449552/how-to-get-time-hhmmss-from-sql-query)

[Referencia 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032915/how-to-cast-the-datetime-to-time)

[Referencia 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629050/sql-server-datetime-like-select)

[Referencia 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187819(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Com esses exemplos não tem mais como ter dúvidas.